# There is no "revision history" option in my Google Survey

Tags: google-forms

I am using Chrome and I am the owner of a survey but I do not have the option of revision history when I click on "File". I really need to view an earlier version of my survey. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

[According to Scott AG](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/qV6weHKrKgI), a Google Expert in the Google Docs Help Forum

> At this time Forms does not contain a revision history.
>
> The only option available would be the undo button found in the
>   toolbar.